# What is the purpose of design rules in VLSI

Tags: cmos, microprocessor, vlsi

My doubt is what does it means micron and lamba design rules? And does it have any connections with nanometer process (eg. 7nm,14nm on microprocessor).

Actually what is the purpose of these design rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like your favorite PCB manufacturer has "rules" (which are more minimum requirements) for your PCB layout (mostly in terms of geometry), an IC Fab also has their own rules to produce your chip design. Also, mostly in terms of the geometry of your physical layout.

Micron rules are the rules stated in absolute metric dimensions, while lambda are stated in "lambda" units. When we had micron processes, lambda-rules were quite nice because all you needed to do is input the new smaller process into the lambda-rules and you got your new design rules. Nowadays, with deep-submicron process, this is not possible anymore, so most of the rules are in absolute units rather than in lambdas.

The reason to have design rules is to ensure that your design can be fabricated with the current equipment (like the lithography machine) such that there's a minimum yield for your designs. Typically, designers to have some margins on top of the minimum requirements to have a safety factor there.